# When and where is the best to initialize reliable collection?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, stateful, service-fabric-stateful

**Scenario**: statefull SF service will store its state in several reliable collections. Statefull SF is available via remoting.

Do I need to "initialize" the collections before the first use (by calling StateManager.GetOrAddAsync)? Will it help lower the first access to reliable collection or it is not necessary to do this step?

If it is advised to do this init, when is right time and place to do it?
The most reasonable place is right before endless loop in RunAsync but what if method called via remoting will be called before the collections are initialized? Is there going to be any deterioration in performance in that first remoting call (when the collection is going to be initialized)?

Last thing -> when working with reliable collections it is OK to hold reference to collection in class (e.g. during some instance initiation I will get the reference by using StateManager.GetOrAddAsync) and working just with this reference or is better to call StateManager.GetOrAddAsync before every call to collection?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to "initialize" the collections before the first use (by calling StateManager.GetOrAddAsync)?

Yes, but you don't have to do that to “warm up” collection. Call that method if you really need retrieve some data or want to store something.

> what if method called via remoting will be called before the collections are initialized?

That's why you need to do `StateManager.GetOrAddAsync` on every call to the service.

> Is there going to be any deterioration in performance in that first remoting call

Yes. But it will be unnoticeable.

> when working with reliable collections it is OK to hold reference to collection in class

You can hold a reference to the collection in a variable within a method call. Here is an example:

```
    public async Task AddPost(Guid userId, PostId postId)
    {
        try
        {
            var state = await StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<Guid, List<PostId>>>(StateName);

            using (var tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction())
            {
                await state.AddOrUpdateAsync(
                    tx,
                    userId,
                    addValue: new List<PostId> {postId},
                    updateValueFactory: (usrId, oldPostsList) =>
                    {
                        oldPostsList.Insert(0, postId);
                        return oldPostsList;
                    }
                );

                await tx.CommitAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            PostsLogger.Singleton.LogWarning("Add post timeout");
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PostsLogger.Singleton.LogException(sb.ToString(), ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!
A little addition to the "hold reference vs. calling GetOrAddAsync" :
Scenario: Wrapper class around reliable collection. Class methods create transaction, store/retrieve data and commit transaction.

It is enough to get the reference to the collection in wrapper initialization/construction or should I call GetOrAddAsync in every method before creating transaction and working with collection?

Are you getting state before every AddPost / RetrievePost?

Comment: You should call `GetOrAddAsync` in every method before creating transaction and working with the collection. Well, of course you can store it in a variable, but I'm not sure that it will work, for example, when several service's methods are called simultaneously. Probably it would work, but I would not recommend this approach. So, yeah, you need to create it on every service's method call. Why not, after all? It is cheap as hell comparing to other operations. I'm getting state on every call to AddPost, just inside the method itself.